# A control for Picture Viewing

Tags: winforms

I need a control for a WinForms application to implement PICTURE VIEWING. The control has to:
- understand multiple image formats;
- to perform Zoom;
- to perform Scrolling when the image is too large to fit to the control area;
- to perform Rotate of the picture (90 degrees to the left and to the right)

The standard Forms.PictureBox, I see, cannot do Scrolling, Zoom and Rotate.
What else can I use?

Comment: Please, first try to accept some answers of your previous question if you got helped with them.

Answer (score 0):

For rotate you can use:

```
pb.Image.RotateFlip(....)
```

For stretching or fit you can use:

```
pb.SizeMode
```

Implementing other functions is not so difficult...